# replacing parameters values with ? in an sql query

Tags: java, sql, regex

Lets say I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES ('Doe',30,'Austin', 'jon@ds.com', 'Jon')
```

I want to replace all the parameters passed in this query with a question mark, to get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Note that this is just an example and a query can be much more complex. I just want to replace all the parameters passed with a question mark.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Normally it is the other way around. Why do this?

Comment: I m capturing the queries made to the data base and don't want to capture parameter values.

Comment: To do this right and handle all possible variations you will need a real SQL parser. Regexes are not up to the task by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple using replaceAll function,

```
String str = "INSERT INTO users (lastname687878, age1, city55,email, firstname66) VALUES (33,30,'Austin', 'jon@ds.com', 'Jon')";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("'.+?'","?").replaceAll(",\\d+", ",?").replaceAll("\\(\\d+", "(?"));
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO users (lastname687878, age1, city55,email, firstname66) VALUES (?,?,?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Not necessarily. The parameters are not always string and can be a number. In this example 30 will not be replaced by ?

Comment: HHey I just run it in eclipse, here dot(.) represent any character may be number or string. If you have doubt just run and check . Looking for your feedback.

Comment: aah i missed that. Thanks, will try it out

Comment: tried it, here is my code

        final String in = "INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES ('Jones155605030',116719280, 'Austin', ' bob2008584593@example.com', 'Bob-2106121947')";
        System.out.println(in.replaceAll("'.+?'","?"));


Here is the output

INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES (?,116719280, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: actually what i meant from number or string is that if the parameter value is not string then there will not be any quotes(') surrounding it

Comment: Hey it's my mistake,sorry for that

Comment: I updated the modified code which also includes the numbers too.

Comment: Last question, the output string with your code may have spaces before or after them based on the given input. Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question, can you explain it briefly